# Getting most tagged posts

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

So I want to find the most posted hashtag for my post system. So here's what my `posts` table looks like

```
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| post_user    | varchar(255)     | NO   |     |         |                |
| post_ip      | varchar(255)     | NO   |     |         |                |
| post_date    | varchar(255)     | NO   |     |         |                |
| post_content | varchar(40)      | NO   |     |         |                |
| post_likes   | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| hashtag      | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Now I want to query through and find the most used `hashtag`. So If I had two posts with the hashtag `cats`, it would return the number of cats, which would be `2`. Then I'd sort in descending order. So `2` for cats, and say `1` for dogs. So essentially the main question is how can I get the most "tagged", hashtag.

Comment: are you storing multiple 'tags' in the hashtag column?

Comment: Does each post only have one hashtag?

Comment: Yes, only one tag @christopher_b

Comment: Just one tag can be used in a post @watcher

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your SQL would look something like:

`SELECT count(hashtag) as c, hashtag FROM posts WHERE hashtag IS NOT NULL GROUP BY hashtag ORDER BY c DESC`

This would return the list of hashtags, sorted by most used. The response will have two columns: c, which is the tag count and the tag itself.

If you just want the single most used tag:

`SELECT count(hashtag) as c, hashtag FROM posts WHERE hashtag IS NOT NULL GROUP BY hashtag ORDER BY c DESC LIMIT 1`

This table design limits you to one hashtag per post. If you wanted to allows posts to have multiple hashtags, you would need a few more tables. Hashtags and posts have a many-to-many relationship: A post can have many tags, and a tag can be used in many posts. To model this, you would need a table for hashtags, and a table that connects posts and tags. The hashtag table could have just an ID column and a column for the tag. The junction table would have a column of the post id and a column for the tag ID. To associate a tag with post, put a row in the junction table that references the tag and the post. You could then remove the hashtag column from the posts table.

Comment: I'm only encountering one issue. Since not everybody will use a hashtag in their post, I have some `NULL` hashtags. Therefore when I run that query I end up getting a `#` with nothing following since its `NULL`. So is there a way I can skip `NULL` hashtags from being queried.